# Что делает inspire vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Что делает `<v-app id="inspire">` ?

Comment: Можете пример показать, какие стили именно меняются, а так же, структуру компонента где Vue рендерите?

Comment: похоже на предопределенную тему. Какие настройки используются?

Comment: @radar4ick позже.

Comment: @Grundy настройки чего?

Comment: настройки vuetify

Comment: @Grundy ничего специфичного я не задавал. Всё дефолтовое. Вечером гляну.

Comment: Можешь сделать пример, что именно меняется? Вот тут вроде бы все остается как есть: https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/zgxeLQ

Comment: @hedgehogues, ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрев исходники и документацию можно сделать вывод что просто задает id для `v-app`, которое по дефолту `app`

В большинстве случаев используют именно `inspire` в случаях когда идет разметка вида:

```
<div id='app'>
  <v-app id='inspire'> ... </v-app>
</div>
```

То есть чтобы не было совпадения `id`. Но нигде не написано что это влияет на стили. Почему именно `inspire` - наверное по той же причине, как и `app` для корневого `div` у `Vue`. Так исторически сложилось =)

Вот [API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/api-explorer/)

Comment: Если его изменить сильно меняются стили. Не ясно, за что отвечает

Comment: Может когда меняешь дефолтный id, то просто все другие стили не могут найти его и примениться?

Comment: Вот это и хотелось бы понять

Comment: В исходниках этого компонента нет вообще упоминания об этом

Comment: Я знаю. Ровно поэтому я и задал этот вопрос